# VueJS messing up my form submit, removing all post data

Tags: jquery, ajax, vue.js

For some reason VueJS is now messing up my form submit, by erasing the post data from the Ajax serialize() function.

I think it may be because I am using Ajax and Jquery, but I'm not sure how to fix.

This code works fine when I'm not using VueJS

```
<script>

$(function(){
   $('#save').click(function () {
   $.ajax({type:'POST', 
   url: 'URL_HERE', 
   data:$('#form').serialize(), success: function(response) {
   alert('saved!');
   }});

   return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

However by adding my VUE code, it no longer submits form data

```
<script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        bgColor: '#FFFFFF',
      }
  });
</script>
```

Parts of the HTML

```
  <div id="app">
    <form method="post" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return false;">
   <!-- various inputs and things in here -->
    </form></div>
```

Any thoughts on why VueJS could be messing up my form submit? Or is it simply not compatible with Ajax / Jquery?

ANSWER: Looks like the answer is that I need the `<div id="app">` inside of the `<form>` tag.

Comment: Can you add your html?

Comment: Bind an onclick event to your form submit and put your ajax call in there.

Comment: The html is pretty lengthy as this is a huge form

Comment: Looks like the answer is that I need the <div id="app"> inside of the <form> tag.

Comment: Not sure why you'd *need* the root element inside the `<form>`. It could also be outside the `<form>`, as shown in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/GXXzOd?editors=1010)

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = (function(){
    
var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        name: ''
      },
      methods: {
          saveMessage() {
              return fetch('https://www.reqres.in/api/users', {
                method: "POST", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
                mode: "cors", // no-cors, cors, *same-origin
                cache: "no-cache", // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
                credentials: "same-origin", // include, same-origin, *omit
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    // "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                },
                redirect: "follow", // manual, *follow, error
                referrer: "no-referrer", // no-referrer, *client
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    'name': this.name
                }), // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
            })
            .then(response => console.log(response.json()));
          }
      }
    })
    
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Vue.js test</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
        <div id="app">
            <form method="post" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return false;">
                <input v-model='name' type="text" placeholder="name" />
                <button @click="saveMessage">Save</button>
            </form>
        </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In general i suggest you to move away from jquery when doing a vue project. For a reason you get a weird look of vue enthusiasts once they spot some jquery code in your project.

> > Vue’s component + Virtual DOM system is very different from jQuery’s DOM manipulation techniques. In Vue, you change data, and your
> >     templates should update automatically, wherein jQuery, you update
> >     data, update DOM yourself.
>
> So updating the DOM with jQuery is not recommended because the next
>   time Vue renders - it will wipe out what you did with jQuery.

You CAN still bring jquery into your Vue Components but it is not recommended, also you get a bigger Package then with jquery(87kb) being as big as vue as whole (86kb).

In terms of moving away from jquery into vue i can recommend you an article with a lot of examples. https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/02/jquery-vue-javascript/